# How to enable Hardware Back key to close app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mobile, mvvmcross

I'm currently writing an MvvmCross app (starting with WP8) that I want to be able to exit by pressing (hardware) Back on the main screen (like normal WP8 apps can be exited). 
Currently pressing Back simply swaps between the last two active pages (?). My BackButton handlers call `this.Close(this)`.
I've read various threads here about clearing the page back stack and custom presenters, but no actual explanation of how to create and integrate a custom presenter in one's app (I've probably missed it in the docs somewhere).

Is there a pointer to how to actually make this work?

Is this the correct way of implementing this across all three platforms? iOS doesn't have a Back button, so how should this be handled correctly?

Comment: If your main screen is the first screen of your app then you shouldn't have any screens back. How you put these two pages below main screen?

Comment: If I don't navigate anywhere from my main screen, `this.Close(this)` in my viewmodel has no effect (the code is executed, but the app does not close). If I navigate to a second screen, then repeated back buttons toggle between those two screens.

Comment: If you don't navigate anywhere from main screen, Back button will close your app automatically. It's default behavior in all Windows Phone apps, you don't have to code anything.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. It doesn't close. I want the standard behavior.

Comment: Ok, user error. I set e.Handled to true in the Button handler. :-(